# Firebase Realtime Database data is loaded too late

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get my data in the table on Firebase Realtime Database. However, when there is a lot of data, it takes minutes to load. Like 5-6 minutes for 500 data.
How can I solve this?

Thanks, best regards.

```
  private void initCustomAdapter() {

        mPeriodsReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                mPeriodsReference.keepSynced(true);
                OnlinePeriod period = dataSnapshot.getValue(OnlinePeriod.class);
                dataList.add(period);
            pageNum = 1;
                Collections.reverse(dataList);
            resfreshListView();
            Log.d("TAG","list coming" + dataList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw error.toException();
            }

        });
        mPeriodsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 1));//
        mPeriodsRecycler.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(Utils.convertDPToPixel(mContext, 3)));
        mTrackAdapter = new TrackListAdapter(mContext, filterDataList);//new ArrayList<CategoryModel>()
        mPeriodsRecycler.setAdapter(mTrackAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: The time it takes to read from the database is usually directly proportional to the amount of data you load, and the bandwidth of the client that loads the data. Can you edit your question to show how you timed this?

Comment: I used to use the onDataChange method and I could see it all in a matter of seconds no matter how large my data was. But in this way I realized that it was consuming too much download quota and I started using the onChildAdded method. When I edit my code for this way, it takes too long for my data to load. I'm waiting 5-6 minutes for just 500 data. The method I use is attached in my code above. Can you help for this?

Comment: There is no difference in the data downloaded between a `ChildEventListener` and a `ValueEventListener`. They download the exact same data, and the only difference is in how they surface that data in your application. You'll want to measure where the time goes in your code, by adding timers/profiling information. For example: you're now refreshing the list for every child node, while I imagine you did it once for all children in `onDataChange`. Is that causing a difference? I'd also recommend moving `mPeriodsReference.keepSynced(true);` outside of `onChildAdded` as it's only needed once.

Comment: `for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    OnlinePeriod period = child.getValue(OnlinePeriod.class);
                    dataList.add(period);
                }`
If i run with this code, i got my data in 1 second.
But I can't run "for" inside the onChildAdded method. I guess that's why my data is loaded too late in the onChildAdded method. What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can deduce by looking at the code given, first you are loading the data into the list `dataList` and then you are reversing the entire list using `Collections.reverse(dataList);` which is an expensive operation.

So, a way around is make your own reversing function to reverse the arraylist because the default `.reverse()` provided by the Collections class is not very efficient.

You can try the below code to reverse the list **in-place** (same ArrayList is used ,hence making it efficient):

```
public ArrayList<Integer> revArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> list) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() / 2; i++) { 
            Integer temp = list.get(i); 
            list.set(i, list.get(list.size() - i - 1)); 
            list.set(list.size() - i - 1, temp); 
        } 
  
        return list; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion i will fix this but this is not the answer to the problem i am having right now.